# Cannot create 'My First App' in Android Studio 1.4 for my Android 2.3.4 device in API 10

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Installed: All Android Studio Packages:
 android-studio-ide-141.2288178-linux.zip
```

Attempted to create 'My First App', but when I select 'Blank Activity'
from 'Add an activity to Mobile', I see:

```
"Selected activity has a minimum build API level of 14."
```

My target device is a **(2010) Motorola DroidX running 2.3.4 (API 10).**

How do I begin to create APPs for my '`API 10' device`?

Answer (score 0):

> Selected activity has a minimum build API level of 14

***Motorola DroidX running 2.3.4 (API 10)***  does not compile with API Level 14 .
So ,

Open **build.gradle** and set `minSdkVersion 14`

After updating the **build.gradle's minSdkVersion**, you have to click on the button to sync gradle file (`"Sync Project with Gradle files"`).

**Example**

```
defaultConfig 
    {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23 //25
    }
```

### Note

**If not works then Set Min API level (Drop-Down Box ) when creating a new Project**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously suggest either migrating to a virtual device (AVD Manager) or finding a more up-to-date device. The link below shows you that only 3.8% of android devices are still running API 10.
Developing in API 10 will seriously limit the capability and availability of functions and target audience respectively.
http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html
Secondly, API 10 doesn't support the idea of adding "Blank Activity" to the project since it requires a project of API 14 as a minimum. This can be set within your androidmanifest.xml. See below for a more in depth explanation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app and open Build.gradle there you can see

```
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 21
```

Change the minSdkVersion 14 to minSdkVersion 10 and Sync or Rebuild your project